# Return Null in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm currently attempting to write a formula that averages together 4 values that may or may not be filled. The formula searches a string for the value in each cell, and it then averages those values together.

The problem is that if the value isn't found, I need it to return `null`, because if I return `0` it doesn't average properly, and a blank `""` value returns a `#VALUE` error, even if wrapped in a the `VALUE()` function and using the `AVERAGEA()` function.

I also tried writing a very simple macro that just returns null, but from what I understand Excel doesn't like that.

So is there some way to return null that I've overlooked? I know that in GoogleSheets the formula `=IFERROR(1/0)` would do the trick - is there a similar workaround?

I'm honestly expecting that I'll have to change the formula to all be in VBA, but I wanted to see if I've overlooked something here.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
So the code I'm using looks like this (I've shortened it down a bit to make it easier):

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(VALUE(MID($AF2, FIND("Hit:", $AF2) + 4, 3)), ""), IFERROR(VALUE(MID($AH2, FIND("Hit:", $AH2) + 4, 3)), ""))
```

In cells AF2 and AH2 are long strings, and the number I'm searching for is always right after it says "Hit:" (if the number is there). So with AVERAGEIF() I'm not sure how to input the range argument there

Comment: Can't you just use an empty string? `""`

Comment: What are you entering in your AVERAGE() function? When used normally it would usually treat an empty string the same way as a null value

Comment: I can't duplicate your error.  Neither text, blank cell, nor `""` give me an error with either `AVERAGE()` or `AVERAGEA()`.  Zero does make a difference, but you can use something like this to ignore zero values: `=AVERAGEIF(C3:C7,">0")` [change range to match]

Comment: @ReyJuna note that `">0"` also ignores negative values while `"<>0"` does only ignore `0`.

Comment: Be aware that in some scenarios a zero might actually occur in the real data, where it *should* count in the average.

Comment: So the code I'm using looks like this (I've shortened it down a bit to make it easier): `= AVERAGE(IFERROR(VALUE(MID($AF2, FIND("Hit:", $AF2) + 4, 3)), ""), IFERROR(VALUE(MID($AH2, FIND("Hit:", $AH2) + 4, 3)), ""))` In cells AF2 and AH2 are long strings, and the number I'm searching for is always right after it says "Hit:" (if the number is there). So with AVERAGEIF() I'm not sure how to input the range argument there.

Comment: @BrettAbraham Please include all codes within the question itself. Add a [mcve] with valid example data so we can easily reproduce your issue. Screenshots might help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to give up on trying to do this without VBA. I wrote a function that just goes through and adds together the values found after the searchFor argument. If anyone ever runs into this issue, here's what I did:

```
'''Searches for a string in each cell in the range, then pulls the value
'''averages together all values that were found offset number of characters away from the string
Function averageWithErrors(searchFor As String, rng As range, offset As Integer, extractLength As Integer) As Double

'Declare Variables
Dim characterPosition As Integer
Dim num As Double
Dim count As Integer
Dim cellCheck As range
Dim cellTotals As Integer


'Set Variables
count = 0
num = 0

'Check each cell
For Each cellCheck In rng
    If InStr(cellCheck.Value, searchFor) Then           'Check if cell has the string
        characterPosition = InStr(cellCheck.Value, searchFor)
        num = num + Val(Mid(cellCheck.Value, characterPosition + offset, extractLength))    'Add the value to the running total
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next cellCheck

averageWithErrors = num / count 'return the average of the values found

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use iferror() to return whatever value you wish:

```
=iferror(your_function,"")
```

or

```
=iferror(your_function,"Check")
```

even numbers...

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to use the AVERAGE() function as an array.  The "" is treated as a string in regular AVERAGE() or SUM() functions, but is seen as a null value in arrays.

Try this (as an array, Ctrl + Shift + Enter):

```
{IFERROR(VALUE(MID($AF2:$AH2, FIND("Hit:", $AF2:$AH2) + 4, 3)), "")}
```

Comment: This almost got there, but unfortunately if one of the cells is missing the value, then the entire thing returns as null. I tried messing around with your suggestion, but couldn't get it to work. I'm going to fool around a bit more and if that doesn't work, I'll just write the formula in VBA.